# Django ugettext with AbstractUser field

Tags: python, django

I use `ugettext_lazy` to translate default `AbstractBaseUser` fields and I've found one problem. I'd like to translate field named `password` to my native language but only thing I recive is

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'password' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractBaseUser'

which is not good.

My code looks like this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    password = models.CharField(_('Parool'), max_length=128)
    ....
```

is there any way to translate all fields from `AbstractBaseUser` or any other defined model? Docs of Django say nothing about my problem.

Funny thing is that I can't translate just this field.

Comment: you have `password` in `AbstractBaseUser` why you define it again in your `User` model?

Comment: Because I want to use translation. As far as I know it's only way to have this field translated in /admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted):

> In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this is not permitted for attributes that are Field instances (at least, not at the moment). If a base class has a field called author, you cannot create another model field called author in any class that inherits from that base class.

Remove or rename `password` field from your model.

If you want to translate `password` field try this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # define your extra fields

AbstractBaseUser._meta.get_field('password').verbose_name = _('Parool')
```

Comment: I can remove this field but then there is no way to translate it as I said in my previous comment.